# DirectoryEntry ChangePassword throws complexity Exception

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I have a local user account. I wish to change the password. To do so, I have the following code:

```
using (DirectoryEntry machineEntries = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + AuthContextName + ", computer"))
{
    DirectoryEntry de = machineEntries.Children.Find(userid, "user"); 
    try
    {
        de.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] {oldpassword, newpassword });
        de.CommitChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.InnerException.Message;
        return false;
    }                                
}
```

I get an Exception at the de.Invoke line:

> The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.

So I check my policy requirements (using Local Group Policy editor):

- 24 passwords remembered
- Max age 42 days
- Min age 1 days
- minimum length 7 chars
- password must meet complexity req **DISABLED**
- store passwords using.... Disabled

The old password is > 1 day old. The new is above 7 chars and has never been used before.

My computer is in a domain, but the user I try to update is local.

What could be the reason for the update to fail?

Comment: Is the value of newpassword what you expect it should be once the debugger gets there? Everything else looks to be configured correctly.

Comment: @Sam Marion: I checked that. The password comes through a URL request, but it is passed correctly to the Invoke method call.

Comment: Do you have any additional security software installed? Sometimes there are additional checks done for password complexity which are not controlled by group policy.

Comment: Also have you tried using a long, complex password? Do you still get the error?

Comment: @Ben: I have anti virus software running.

Comment: I have unflagged "password never expires" today on this user account. Although the account password is older than 1 day, maybe this resets the age to 0...?

Comment: Anything other security software e.g. full disk encryption or hardware token?

Comment: @Ben: Nothing comes to mind regarding other security software.

Comment: Have you tried using a complex password?

Comment: @Ben 12 chars with small and big letters, numbers and a "#". Later today I will check if removing the "password never expires" flag is resetting password age. So far this is my only idea for a solution.

Comment: Does it contain any part of the user name?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994562(v=ws.11).aspx   Also try setting "user must change password on next logon" flag as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994570(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @Ben I tried now with a new password that does not have user id within it. Note that Complexity requirements are disabled.

Comment: @Ben "User must change the password at next login" did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: @Ben Based on the above tests I did, would you say that the failure to update is caused by the Minimum Age rule?

Comment: Yes. Minimum age rule is stupid, and it is certainly going to make it hard for you to do your testing anyway! Note "1 day" means 24 hours, not one calendar day.

Comment: @Ben If you wish to write the "User must change the password at next login" as an answer to my question, I will accept it.

Comment: It's not really the answer though.